# Selinux: Shorewall will not respond to fail2ban

Tags: fedora, selinux, fail2ban, shorewall

I am using fail2ban with shorewall and my Fedora 21 server & cloud. All flooded with the following error message:

```
SELinux is preventing shorewall from write access on the file /tmp/fai2ban*.[stderr|stdout] (deleted). For complete SELinux messages. run sealert -l ...
```

Of course, fail2ban shows that an ip is banned but shorewall does not actually ban it.

Running `sealert -l` on the specified file will not produce anything since the file is deleted.

The same happens when I am trying to make the relevant policy active:

```
[root@fedora server]# semodule -i shorewall.pp
libsepol.print_missing_requirements: shorewall's global requirements were not met: type/attribute shorewall_t (No such file or directory).
libsemanage.semanage_link_sandbox: Link packages failed (No such file or directory).
semodule:  Failed!
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, where is your Bugzilla bug report? You should have filed a bug report first.

Comment: OK, [report filed](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1231367).